# Device connectivity, due to low disk space

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I am getting this error message while running the application in the device emulator.

Error Message :

`Deployment and/or registration failed with error: 0x8973190e.
Error writing file '%csidl_program_files%'
Error 0x80070070: There is not enough space on the disk.
   Device Connectivity Component`

Please suggest me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emulators and devices have much less room than a PC. Either uninstall some apps on your emulator/device or reduce the size of your executable.